# Show that the operator is NOT symmetric.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

Show that the Sturm-Liouville operator $L$ in $L^2([a,b])$ given by $$L=\frac{1}{r(x)}\left(DpD+q\right)$$ is not symmetric.

I'm assuming $p=p(x)>0$ and $q=q(x)\geq 0$, as described by the problem directly above this problem in the textbook I'm studying from (just so you know). Is that reasonable?

For an operator to be symmetric, it has to satisfy $\langle Lx,y\rangle=\langle x,Ly\rangle$, $\forall x,y\in L^2([a,b])$, correct? This looks the same as the definition for self-adjoint. Are they the same?

I'm not quite sure how to proceed. Any help/hints would be useful.

Comment: No, this is incorrect. $\forall x,y \in dom(L)$ we have $\langle Lx, y \rangle = \langle x, Ly\rangle$, hence $L$ is symmetric. And $L = L^*$ is definition of self-adjoint, which basically means that $L$ is symmetric and $dom(L) = dom(L^*)$ . Notice, that by definition you have an inclusion $dom(L) \subset dom(L^*)$.

Comment: @echzhen Why?  $dom(L)$ is "domain of operator $L$", correct?  The operator $L$ is in the space $L^2([a,b])$.

Comment: No. $L : L^2([a,b]) \supset Dom(L) \mapsto L^2([a,b])$

Comment: So self-adjoint operators are symmetric, but symmetric operators are not necessarily self-adjoint?

Comment: yes, you get it right!

Comment: It is symmetric in $L^2_{r}[a,b]$, where $(f,g)_{L^2_r}=\int f\overline{g}rdx$, assuming that $r > 0$ on $(a,b)$ so that $L^2_{r}(a,b)$ makes sense, provided you have appropriate endpoint conditions on $\mathcal{D}(L)$. It is not symmetric on $L^2(a,b)$ unless $r=1$ a.e..